# How to get wacom tablet to work on my acer chromebook 13 under chrubuntu?

Tags: acer, tablet, chromebook, wacom

I've tried to build the drivers below is my output when and try and `make` and `make install`:

```
make

make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/user/Downloads/input-wacom-0.27.0'
Making all in 3.7
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/user/Downloads/input-wacom-0.27.0/3.7'
    Building input-wacom drivers for 2.6 kernel.
make -C /lib/modules/3.10.18/build M=/home/user/Downloads/input-wacom-0.27.0/3.7
make[3]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.10.18'
  CC [M]  /home/user/Downloads/input-wacom-0.27.0/3.7/wacom_wac.o
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.10.18/scripts/recordmcount: 1: /usr/src/linux-headers-3.10.18/scripts/recordmcount: Syntax error: end of file unexpected
make[4]: *** [/home/user/Downloads/input-wacom-0.27.0/3.7/wacom_wac.o] Error 2
make[3]: *** [_module_/home/user/Downloads/input-wacom-0.27.0/3.7] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.10.18'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Downloads/input-wacom-0.27.0/3.7'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Downloads/input-wacom-0.27.0'
make: *** [all] Error 2

make install

Making install in 3.7
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/user/Downloads/input-wacom-0.27.0/3.7'
make -C /lib/modules/3.10.18/build M=/home/user/Downloads/input-wacom-0.27.0/3.7 modules_install
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.10.18'
  DEPMOD  3.10.18
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.10.18'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Downloads/input-wacom-0.27.0/3.7'
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/user/Downloads/input-wacom-0.27.0'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/user/Downloads/input-wacom-0.27.0'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Downloads/input-wacom-0.27.0'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Downloads/input-wacom-0.27.0'
```

Comment: "Syntax error: end of file unexpected" either your download is corrupt or you need to contact the person who wrote the code.